# Print first occurrence of each unique regex match with line number

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Given a regex, I want to print first occurrence of each unique match with its line number using bash.

For example, lets say the regex is `.*Exception`, I want to print,

```
$./script.sh file.log
6255:2016-09-07 10:05:37,886 ERROR some text java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
6714:2016-09-07 10:12:09,514 ERROR some text java.lang.NullPointerException
7013:2016-09-07 10:19:19,950 ERROR some text java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I came up with a version, but it is very slow :( (on git-bash). Any pointers on how to increase performance is appreciated.

```
FILE_NAME=$1

while read line
do
    grep "$line" "$FILE_NAME" -m1 -n
done < <(grep '\b[^ ]*Exception\b' "$FILE_NAME" | sort -u) | sort -n
```

Update (adding sample data):

```
2016-09-07 23:58:55,674 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:56:16,273 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:58:26,304 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
```

Above should produce:

```
2:2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
4:2016-09-07 23:56:16,273 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
5:2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
```

Comment: If you would post some of that `file.log` for test material, I believe more people would like to try and solve your problem. Some hits and misses would be nice.

Comment: will `perl` solution be acceptable?

Comment: `perl` should be ok as long as its not too cryptic.

Comment: so, `XAException` is the exception name in 2nd line of your output?

Comment: Yes, as it matches the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
2016-09-07 23:58:55,674 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:56:16,273 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) Continuing ...
2016-09-07 23:58:26,304 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR

$ perl -ne '($e)=/(\w+Exception)/; print "$.:$_" if !$seen{$e}++ && /Exception/' ip.txt
2:2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
4:2016-09-07 23:56:16,273 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
5:2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
```

- `($e)=/(\w+Exception)/` saves the type of exception in `$e` variable
- `!$seen{$e}++` makes sure only first line matching the exception is printed
- `&& /Exception/` to print only lines containing `Exception`
- `print "$.:$_"` print line number, `:` and the input line

**Edit:**

This should work too and faster...

```
perl -ne 'if(/(\w+Exception)/){print "$.:$_" if !$seen{$1}++}' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu awk:

```
$ awk '/Exception/ && !seen[gensub(/^([^ ]* ){2}/,"","g")]++ {print NR,$0}' file.log
2 2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
4 2016-09-07 23:56:16,273 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-12) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.XAException, XAException.XAER_RMERR
5 2016-09-07 23:58:55,675 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-18-thread-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
```

Print record if:

- `/Exception/` matches
- `&&` and
- `!seen[...]++` key hasn't been seen earlier
- `gensub(/^([^ ]* ){2}/,"","g")` key created by removing from start `^` to second space
- `print NR,$0` print current record number and record